# Change the img source based on a specific image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, tags

I have a page that has several icon images that need changing. I cannot get to the images by ID as they are generated by the server so always change, but I can get to them by a class name.

So I want to change say just 4 of the several icon images on the page by getting the image source and checking it matches the criteria of the image I want to change and then swap in the new icon image.

I have some clunky versions in javascript and JQuery but I'm really looking for a slick version that's functional and simple.

I did find this worked fine for 4 separate images needing changing in multiple locations:

```
 function changeArrow() {
            $('img[src="chevron-orange-round-down.jpg"]').attr('src', 'chevron-blue-round-down.jpg')
            $('img[src="chevron-orange-round-up.jpg"]').attr('src', 'chevron-blue-round-up.jpg') 
            $('img[src="chevron-orange-round-left.jpg"]').attr('src', 'chevron-blue-round-left.jpg') 
            $('img[src="chevron-orange-round-right.jpg"]').attr('src', 'chevron-blue-round-right.jpg') 
        }
```

I expected that I'd need a loop such as .each as suggested below but this changed all instances of image that met the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the src attr `$('.image').attr('src', 'val');`

or by a simple loop

```
$('.image').each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).attr('src')=='some criteria')
    {
    $(this).attr('src', 'val');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so I have something like this:

$('img[src="red-arrow-up.jpg"]').attr('src', 'blue-arrow-up.jpg') // repeat per image

Comment: I'll give it a try shortly - looks good though, I'll update you when done, cheers

Comment: I found the first example slightly modified worked fine without the need for a loop. Thanks for the help

Comment: Have done but it's new account so not showing upvote just yet, not sure where the accept is ??

Comment: you can tick the checkbox beside ans